# Анализ вложенных ссылок на странице

Tags: javascript, link, promise

есть 2 страницы вики мы должны узнать можно ли с данной страницы(#1) по ссылкам попасть на искомую нами страницу(#2). Уровень вложенности может доходить до 4 страниц.

например searchWiki('Microsoft', 'Nintendo').then(res) {
  console.log (res);
});
// ожидаемый результат:
// ['Microsoft', 'XBox', 'GameCube', 'Nintendo']

запрос отправляем с помощью JSONP - http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=title&prop=text&section=0&format=json&callback=func

интересует логика выплнения.ъ
по первой выборке ссылок их количество равняется 170 - в каждой ссылке еще по ~170 и того 170 * 170 * 170 * 170 = 800 000 000

помогите!!!

Answer (score 1):

800 000 000 страниц чесать вероятнее всего не придется
как только вам при прочесывании массива попадается страница, которая в рамках 4 вложений ссылается на конечную страницу, поиск прекращается и (попасть с #1 на #2) = true;